# How to define custom loss in Keras with varying values?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to define my loss function such that it takes into account the MSE between the input and output of my autoencoder, plus the MSE between the code and its true value that I am calling S.

My AE is defined as below:

```
input_fts = Input(shape=(self.input_length,), name='ae_input')

encoded = Dense(1826, activation='relu', name='e_dense1')(input_fts)
encoded = Dense(932, activation='relu', name='e_dense2')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(428, activation='relu', name='e_dense3')(encoded)

encoded = Dropout(0.1)(encoded)
code = Dense(self.encoding_length, activation='relu', name='code')(encoded)

decoded = Dense(428, activation='relu', name='d_dense4')(code)
decoded = Dense(932, activation='relu', name='d_dense5')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(1826, activation='relu', name='d_dense6')(decoded)
output_fts = Dense(self.output_length, activation='relu', name='ae_output')(decoded)

ae = Model(inputs=input_fts, outputs=output_fts)
ae.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=ModelFactory.custom_loss(code, self.S, self.lambda_), metrics=['mae', 'acc'])
```

My custom loss as:

```
@staticmethod
def custom_loss(layer, S, lambda_):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1) + lambda_ * K.mean(K.square(layer - S[0, :]), axis=-1)

    return loss
```

This works but it is not quite what I want. I want the example in S to be chosen based on the example being evaluated at the time, so S[0, :] would be S[i, :], where "i" is the example's index.

The variable "layer" is a tensor of shape [None, 312]. The variable S is a NumPy array o shape [1194, 312], where 1194 is the number of examples I have in my training set. My guess was that I had to transform S into some type of tensor too. So I tried:

```
self.S = K.variable(S)
```

And changed custom_loss to:

```
... lambda_ * K.mean(K.square(layer - S), axis=-1)
```

The problem now is that I get shape mismatch between my batch and S:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [128] vs. [1194]
```

AE training is configured as:

```
self.model.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=nepochs, batch_size=128, shuffle=True, verbose=1,
                                      validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[classification])
```

How can I make S vary with the batch size too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, S is essentially just another input to your model. In that case you can add a second input layer for S and pass S to the model during training. This would make something like:

```
input_fts = Input(shape=(self.input_length,), name='ae_input')
S_in = Input(shape=(312,), name='s_input')

encoded = Dense(1826, activation='relu', name='e_dense1')(input_fts)
encoded = Dense(932, activation='relu', name='e_dense2')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(428, activation='relu', name='e_dense3')(encoded)

encoded = Dropout(0.1)(encoded)
code = Dense(self.encoding_length, activation='relu', name='code')(encoded)

decoded = Dense(428, activation='relu', name='d_dense4')(code)
decoded = Dense(932, activation='relu', name='d_dense5')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(1826, activation='relu', name='d_dense6')(decoded)
output_fts = Dense(self.output_length, activation='relu', name='ae_output')(decoded)

ae = Model(inputs=[input_fts, S_in], outputs=output_fts)

ae.add_loss(self.lambda_ * K.mean(K.square(S_in-code)))
ae.add_loss(K.mean(K.square(input_fts - output_fts)))

ae.compile(optimizer='adam')
```

You then pass both your normal input and S to predict by using lists (see https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/).